# How to properly serve an object detection model from Tensorflow Object Detection API?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-serving

I am using Tensorflow Object Detection API(github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/object_detection) with one object detection task. Right now I am having problem on serving the detection model I trained with Tensorflow Serving(tensorflow.github.io/serving/).

**1.** The first issue I am encountering is about exporting the model to servable files.
The object detection api kindly included the export script so that I am able to convert ckpt files to pb files with variables. However, the output files will not have any content in 'variables' folder. I though this was a bug and reported it on Github, but it seems they interned to convert variables to constants so that there will be no variables. The detail can be found [HERE](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2045).

The flags I was using when exporting the saved model is as follows:

```
    CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python export_inference_graph.py \
        --input_type image_tensor \
            --pipeline_config_path configs/rfcn_resnet50_car_Jul_20.config \
                --checkpoint_path resnet_ckpt/model.ckpt-17586 \
                    --inference_graph_path serving_model/1 \
                      --export_as_saved_model True
```

It runs perfectly fine in python when I switch --export_as_saved_model to False.

But still, I am having issue with serving the model.

When I was trying to run:

```
~/serving$ bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/tensorflow_model_server --port=9000 --model_name=gan --model_base_path=<my_model_path>
```

I got:

```
2017-07-27 16:11:53.222439: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:155] Restoring SavedModel bundle.
2017-07-27 16:11:53.222497: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:165] The specified SavedModel has no variables; no checkpoints were restored.
2017-07-27 16:11:53.222502: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:190] Running LegacyInitOp on SavedModel bundle.
2017-07-27 16:11:53.229463: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:284] Loading SavedModel: success. Took 281805 microseconds.
2017-07-27 16:11:53.229508: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:86] Successfully loaded servable version {name: gan version: 1}
2017-07-27 16:11:53.244716: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/main.cc:290] Running ModelServer at 0.0.0.0:9000 ...
```

I think the model was not properly loaded since it shows "The specified SavedModel has no variables; no checkpoints were restored."

But since we have converted all variables into constants, it seems reasonable. I am not sure here.

**2**. I was not able to use client to call server and do detection on a sample image.

The client scrip is listed below:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import absolute_import

# Communication to TensorFlow server via gRPC
from grpc.beta import implementations
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
# TensorFlow serving stuff to send messages
from tensorflow_serving.apis import predict_pb2
from tensorflow_serving.apis import prediction_service_pb2


# Command line arguments
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('server', 'localhost:9000',
                       'PredictionService host:port')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('image', '', 'path to image in JPEG format')
FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS


def load_image_into_numpy_array(image):
    (im_width, im_height) = image.size
    return np.array(image.getdata()).reshape(
    (im_height, im_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)

def main(_):
    host, port = FLAGS.server.split(':')
    channel = implementations.insecure_channel(host, int(port))
    stub = prediction_service_pb2.beta_create_PredictionService_stub(channel)

    # Send request
    request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
    image = Image.open(FLAGS.image)
    image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
    image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
    # Call GAN model to make prediction on the image
    request.model_spec.name = 'gan'
    request.model_spec.signature_name = 'predict_images'
    request.inputs['inputs'].CopyFrom(
    tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(image_np_expanded))

    result = stub.Predict(request, 60.0)  # 60 secs timeout
    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

To match `request.model_spec.signature_name = 'predict_images'`, I modified the exporter.py script in object detection api (github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/exporter.py) started at line 289 from:

```
          signature_def_map={
          signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY:
              detection_signature,
      },
```

To:

```
          signature_def_map={
          'predict_images': detection_signature,
          signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY:
              detection_signature,
      },
```

Since I have no idea how to call a default signature key.

When I run the following command:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/client --server=localhost:9000 --image=<my_image_file>
```

I got following error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xinyao/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/client.runfiles/tf_serving/tensorflow_serving/example/client.py", line 54, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/xinyao/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/client.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/home/xinyao/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/client.runfiles/tf_serving/tensorflow_serving/example/client.py", line 49, in main
    result = stub.Predict(request, 60.0)  # 60 secs timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grpc/beta/_client_adaptations.py", line 324, in __call__
    self._request_serializer, self._response_deserializer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grpc/beta/_client_adaptations.py", line 210, in _blocking_unary_unary
    raise _abortion_error(rpc_error_call)
grpc.framework.interfaces.face.face.AbortionError: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.NOT_FOUND, details="FeedInputs: unable to find feed output ToFloat:0")
```

Not quite sure what's going on here.

Initially I though maybe my client script is not correct, after I found the AbortionError is from github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f488419cd6d9256b25ba25cbe736097dfeee79f9/tensorflow/core/graph/subgraph.cc. Seems I got this error when building the graph. So it might be caused by the first issue I have.

I am new to this stuff, so I am really confused. I think I might be wrong at start. Is there any way that I could properly export and serve the detection model? Any suggestions will be of great help!

Comment: I get `code=StatusCode.FAILED_PRECONDITION, details="Serving signature key "predict_images" not found."` . I updated the exporter.py file as per ur code though. any ideas ?

Comment: @PamioSolanky As you can see original code of exporter.py line 276-277, I made some modification. Instead using signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY as the serving signature key, I changed it to 'predict_images'. So I was able to call it using the client code I posted above. If you did not change that, you will probably use default serving signature key, or assign your own key by adding it to your flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current exporter code doesn't populate signature field properly. So serving using model server doesn't work. Apologies to that. A new version to better support exporting the model is coming. It includes some important fixes and improvements needed for serving, especially serving on Cloud ML Engine. See the [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1811) if you want to try an early version of it.

For "The specified SavedModel has no variables; no checkpoints were restored." message, it is expected due to the exact reason you said, as all variables are converted into constants in the graph. For the error of "FeedInputs: unable to find feed output ToFloat:0", make sure you use TF 1.2 when building the model server.

Comment: Thank you for your update.
For the error of "FeedInputs: unable to find feed output ToFloat:0", I am using the default tensorflow version from tensorflow_serving, I rebuilt tensorflow_serving again today with tensorflow comitment 16d39e94e3724417fcaed87035434e098e892842 and up-to-date tf_models but the error is still there. I will try to update the tf_models that I am using to export my model later(I have 2 tf_models in separate folders, one for serving and one for object_detection) and see if that will resolve the problem.

Comment: I tried update export script and was able to get it running, but it seems only using CPU instead of GPU to do inference, do you know what might cause this problem?

Answer (score 2):

1. Your idea is fine. It' ok to have that warning.
2. The issue is that the input needs to be converted to `uint8` as the model expects. Here is the code snippet that worked for me.

> ```
> request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
> request.model_spec.name = 'gan'
> request.model_spec.signature_name = 
>     signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY
>
> image = Image.open('any.jpg')
> image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
> image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
>
> request.inputs['inputs'].CopyFrom(
>     tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(image_np_expanded, 
>         shape=image_np_expanded.shape, dtype='uint8'))
> ```

This part is important for you **shape=image_np_expanded.shape, dtype='uint8'** and make sure to pull the latest update for serving.

Comment: For me, this method partially worked, but did not give me as good of results compared to other methods (missing detections etc).  Instead I exported the model using `--input_type encoded_image_string_tensor` and sent the jpeg data directly `data = image.read(); request.inputs['inputs'].CopyFrom(tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(data, shape=[1]))`

Comment: this snippet will work only for the models which expect image pixels (--input_type image_tensor) as input. In your case, it's encoded image, not pixels. That's why it didn't work I think.

Comment: At least for me, this snippet combined with `--input_type image_tensor` 'worked' in that it will return detection results.  However, when I exported using `--input_type encoded_image_string_tensor` and sent the encoded image, I got much better results, like 10 detections in an image as opposed to 3-4 with your method.  Your method would return some detections so it appeared to be working, but wasn't working as well as I expected considering how the model behaved on my evaluation set during training.  My method performed closer to my expectation.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the exact problem. I was trying to host the pre-trained SSDMobileNet-COCO checkpoint from Tensorflow Object Detection API Zoo

Turns out I was using an old commit of tensorflow/models which happens to be the default sub-module of serving

I simply pulled the recent commit with

`cd serving/tf_models
git pull origin master
git checkout master`

After that, built the model server again.

`bazel build //tensorflow_serving/model_servers:tensorflow_model_server`

The error went away and I was able to get accurate predictions

Comment: I tried the above instruction but still not work, would you like to share your python client script with me?

Comment: I used an exact copy of your client script to test my configuration out and it worked. Please try pulling the latest commit of object_detection because the exporter scripts have changed and are more sophisticated now.

Comment: To use GPU for inference, make sure you have built Tensorflow Serving for GPU. This thread has proper instructions to set that up https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/345

Answer (score 0):

For the error

`grpc.framework.interfaces.face.face.AbortionError: 
AbortionError(code=StatusCode.NOT_FOUND, details="FeedInputs: unable to find feed output ToFloat:0"`

Just upgrade the tf_models to the latest version, and re-export the model.

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11863

Comment: Thanks for reference, I tried but still not working for my case.

Comment: It is working, but it seems only using CPU instead of GPU to do inference, do you know what might cause this problem?

Comment: compile tf-serving for GPU need some special tricks which not in the docs. Check this out: https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/459

Comment: Thank you so much!